# Suppose two balanced dice are thrown. What are the possible values of the following random variables :

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose two balanced dice are thrown. What are the possible values of the following random variables

$X:$ The maximum value of the results on the dice.

$Y:$ The minimum value of the results on the dice.

Calculate the probabilities associated with the random variables.

The maximum value to obtain in the dice is $6$, and the minimum is $1$. The probability of obtaining these results is $1/36$. I do not understand what you mean by the values for the random variables.

Comment: If the scores on the dice are $a$ and $b$, then $X=\max(a,b)$ and $Y=\min(a,b)$. For example, $P(X=5)$ is the probability that the bigger of the scores on the dice is 5.

Comment: @a1402 So X and Y have the same values, they are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: If I get (1, 1), then the maximum value is 1?

Comment: The probability associated with the random variable X, is $P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)+P(X=6)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the two random (independent) dice values are $A$ and $B$. I suggest you make a table that shows the value of random variable $X=\max(A,B)$ for each of the possible values of $(A,B)$, like this: $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline\text{A \ B}&1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 
\hline 1&1&2&3&4&5&6\\ \hline 2&2&2&3&4&?&?\\ \hline 3&3&3&3&?&?&?\\ \hline 4&?&?&?&?&?&?\\ \hline 5&?&?&5&?&?&?\\ \hline 6&?&?&?&?&?&?\\  \hline \end{array}$$
There are $6\times 6=36$ entries, and all are equally likely. Exactly three of the entries are $2$s, so $P(X=2)=3/36=1/12$.  The "probabilities associated with random variable $X$" are just the individual values of $P(X=x)$ for $x=1,2,3,4,5,6.$ (Likewise for the random variable $Y=\min(A,B)$, for which you can make a similar table.)

Comment: Just to be sure, $P(X=1)=1/36$, $P(X=5)=9/36$?

Comment: @KittyM. That's right. (Notice the pattern? The value $x$ occurs in this table $2x-1$ times.)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KittyM. One caveat: In the problem statement, "probabilities associated with the random variables" could also be understood to mean the *joint probabilities* $P(X=x,Y=y)$. In that case, we can make a similar $6\times 6$ table showing the value of the *random pair* $(X,Y)$ for each possible $(A,B)$. The probabilities $P(X=x,Y=y)$ are then found in the same way, as the number of favorable cases out of $36$.

Comment: Now that you've mentioned it, it could be. Again, thank you very much for everything.